# Set a drawable as background programmatically

Tags: android, json, drawable

**EDIT: Sorry I realise from your comment my question was not clear enough. I will post a new one. Sorry for this and thanks for your answers**

I am populating a ListView from a Json file.

With my **listadapter**, I can easily assign appropriate json data to each row of my list. That works well for text, for example:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.descView);   
tv.setText(i.desc);
```

With the above code, every row will be correctly populated by the good json data.

However, I don't manage to do the same thing for an image. I have tried to set the right image from my json data using this:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.imgView);           
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(i.img));
```

I guess I am doing something wrong with the type of my parameters: "setBackgroundDrawable" requires a drawable parameter.
"getDrawable" requires an int.
I have set the type of my field img to int, but that doesn't work.

Any idea why?

My **list adapter**:

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItems> {

int resource;
String response;
Context context;

//Initialize adapter
public ListItemsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ListItems> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource=resource; 
}     

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    //Get the current object
    ListItems i = getItem(position);

    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li;
        li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        li.inflate(resource, ll, true);
    }
    else
    {
        ll = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    //For the message
    TextView tv = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.descView);
    tv.setText(i.desc);

// For the Img
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    iv.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(i.img));

    return ll;
}
```

my **item class**:

```
    public class ListItems{
int id;
int img;    
String desc;}
```

And a sample of my json file:

```
    [{"id":10001,"img":e1,"desc":"desc1"},
    {"id":10002,"img":e2,"desc":"desc2"},
    {"id":10003,"img":e3,"desc":"desc3"}]
```

Comment: probably you want to use setImageResources wich take an int as parameter and set the src of your imageview. Still the problem is not realted to setBackgroundDrawable. Also your code can not worlìk.  ll does not contains either the textview and the imageview

Comment: What is e1 means? Where is the image in your json data?

Comment: can you post "resource" layout

Comment: are e1,e2,e3 the names of drawable images which you want to set?

Answer (score 57):

Try this

```
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img));
```

or

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
```

Comment: should use iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);

Comment: @CorayThan How to achieve this in previous API versions(<= 15) ?

Comment: @CorayThan did you find a solution to old apis?

Answer (score 14):

Now as `getDrawable` and `setBackgroundDrawable` both are `depricated` you should set drawable as Background like this :

```
view.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

and if you are targating *minSdk below 16* then make a check like this :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable));
    } else {
        view.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **change the ImageView image/src**,

1. In Layout `android:src="@drawable/img"` or `app:srcCompat="@drawable/img"`
2. Programmatically `imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);`

If you want to **change the background of ImageView**

1. In Layout `android:background="@drawable/img"`
2. programmatically `selectimg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_filled);`

Here **imageview** is a ImageView and **img** is a drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Here the new Method

```
recyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_button_shape);
```

don't use this it's an old method

```
recyclerView.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(edit_text_button_shape));
```